# sourcing functions in file with has gui_running from .vimrc

Tags: vim

Currently running:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Sep  1 2012 18:08:47)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-646
Compiled by Bjorn Winckler <bjorn.winckler@gmail.com>
```

I have these lines in my .vimrc

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  source ~/.vim/vimrc/mygfuncs.vim
endif
```

In the mygfuncs file are some functions that set the `guitablabel` and `guitabtooltip` based on two custom functions. The file is being sourced (because the functions are defined), but the lines that set those variables using those functions aren't working:

```
set guitabtooltip=%{GuiTabToolTip()}
set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
```

At this point, the variables are set properly, because if I

```
:set guitabtooltip
```

Vim responds with

```
guitabtooltip=%{GuiTabToolTip()}
```

But it isn't actually being applied.

**But** if I then `:so ~/.vimrc`, the tab label and tooltips *are* applied.

What is going on here?

Comment: In what file do you have the `set guitabtooltip=%{GuiTabToolTip()}` and `set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}` lines? Did you try in a new MacVim instance? In the same instance? I have a `toto.vim` with 2 elements: a `Toto()` function that returns `toto` and `set guitabtooltip=%{Toto()}`. The file is sourced in my `~/.vimrc` and works as expected.

Comment: I have the set functions in the mygfuncs file. And that file is being sourced, because the two functions are defined...but they aren't actually being applied because I have to so my .vimrc again to get the functions to be applied to my tabs.

Comment: One useful tip I use for debugging is putting the line `echohl Error | echo "Debug string here" | echohl None` in strategic places. I'd put it after the `if has("gui_macvim")` line to see whether that conditional is evaluating to true.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only time it will be properly executed is when you have the code block:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
   source ~/.vim/vimrc/mygfuncs.vim
endif
```

... in a self contained ~/.gvimrc file.